# Removing AZ from AWS Network LB using aws-cli

Tags: scripting, aws-cli

I am  having an issue removing AZ's from a Network Loadbalancer  in AWS.   So much so that I believe it's not possible.

Using  the AWS CLI I saw you could use `aws elbv2 set-subnets --load-balancer-arn [arn] --subnets [list]`

But this is not possible with Network Subnets: `An error occurred (InvalidConfigurationRequest) when calling the SetSubnets operation: SetSubnets is not supported for load balancers of type 'network'`

Is there anything other than deleting the load-balancer and recreating that can be done to remove/deactivate AZ's on a network LB?

Looking through the docs it's appearing to be a no-go at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`set_subnets()` documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.set_subnets) says:

> You can't change the subnets for a Network Load Balancer.